# Ubuntu 18.04: frequent freeze and 'System Program Problem'

Tags: 18.04

Recently I start to experience quite frequent system problems and I wonder how to trouble shoot my system to understand what's gone wrong and fix it.

There are two types of faults I experience often

1. System freezes for no reason, often very suddenly. And basically the system is not responding to any input at all, mouse cursor not moving, key pressing, etc. I can only hard-shutdown the laptop by pressing the power button, then start the computer again.

Upon booting, **sometimes** I get a screen that asks me to run a check using **fcsk** (I think? I dont have a screenshot now). When I do it, it shows that some system files are fixed, then I can restart by computer and it enters Ubuntu normally.

However, this does not always happen.

Also, even if I have done this, the freeze can still happen randomly next time. And this does not seem to link to any software I am running because I did not install software in the last 3 months but this only happened in the last month.

2. I keep getting 'System Program Problem' pop up window that asks me to send a report to developers. Today, I think I got it more than 10 times. See a screenshot like below. But I do not know what these mean.

[image]

So my question is how can I run a proper diagnosis of my system to find out what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The `.crash` files in `/var/crash` are text files. Read them with `less` or `more`.

Comment: Something is really wrong with your system. The kernel shouldn't be crashing like it is. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and screenshots of the `Disks` application SMART Data window. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: thanks for all your help. I do not need this question to beanswered anymore. I did a system reinstall and hopefully this will not happen.